# misalignment datatables thead and tbody (which appear in 2 different tables)

Tags: datatables

I have an alignement problem with datatables. I checked other topics about this but still un resolved.
I generate a tbody with json datas, and first problem, the tbody is generated in a different table. This way, I have on one hand the head of the table, and on the other, the body. Really weird to me.
Second thing, and for me it's because of the first point, the head and the body are not aligned.

I precise that this is a project on which I took the hand. So I didn't build it myself, and I'm not relly comfortable with datatables.

Here is the source code :

```
<table border="0" id="articleStatsByUser">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nom</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>      
      <th>Nom du compte</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Marque</th>      
      <th>DE</th>
      <th>Nb<br>d'articles<br>consultés</th>
      <th>DO</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Login</th>
      <th>Date de dernière connexion</th>
      <th>Date de dernière connexion échouée</th>
      <th>Nb de connexions depuis l'espace privé</th>
      <th>Nb de connexions depuis la Newsletter</th>
      <th>Droit d'accès</th>
      <th>OCRM-ID</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

var info = false;
var paginate = false;
var filter = true;

var viewDetailLink = '<%= viewDetailLink %>';
var jsonData = <%= userViewsJson %>;

$(document).ready(function($) {

     var oTable = $('#articleStatsByUser').dataTable( {
       "bInfo": info,
       "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
       "oTableTools": {
           "sSwfPath": "/html/js/datatables/extras/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
           "aButtons": [{"sExtends": "xls","sButtonText": 'Export le résultat en Excel', "sTitle": "statistiques-clients - COMPASS GROUP France"}]},
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
       "sScrollY": "400px",
       "sScrollX": "100%",
       "bPaginate": paginate,
       "bFilter": filter,
       "bScrollCollapse": true,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bDeferRender": true,
       "aaData": jsonData,
       "aoColumns": [
         { 
          "mData": "userName",
          "id": "userName"
        },
         { 
           "mData": "userFirstName"
         },
         {
         "mData": "userJob",
         "id": "userJob"
         },
         { 
           "mData": "userSite"
         },
         {
         "mData": "groupUser",
         "id": "groupUser"
         },
         { 
           "mData": "userDE",
         "id": "userDE"
         },
         { 
           "mData": "nbArticlesViews"
         },
         { 
           "mData": "userDO",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "userEmail",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "userScreenName",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "lastLoginDateExpr",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "lastFailedLoginDateExpr",
           "bVisible":    false
         }, 
         { 
           "mData": "nbConnexions",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "nbConnexionsNewsletter",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "droitAcces",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         { 
           "mData": "userOCRMID",
           "bVisible":    false
         },
         {        
         "mData": null,
         "bSortable": false,
         "mRender": function( cell, type, row ){
               if (type === 'display')
                 return '<a href="'+ viewDetailLink + row.userScreenName +'" title="Voir la liste des articles"><img src="/html/icons/zoom-icon.png"></a>';
               return cell;
           }
         }
       ]});
}
</script>
```

[image: stat_example]

I really need some help on this one.
Thanks

Comment: The header and body shouldn't be in different tables - is the json returning <tr> and <td> tags?

Comment: I agree with you, it shouldn't. No, it doesn't return tr and td tags, only plain text datas.
But I solved it : Actually, in css, there were :
`#articleStatsByUser > thead {
    display: none;
}`

When I suppressed it, a double thead appeared in firefox, but not in chrome and ie. I then replaced `display: none;` with `height: 0px;`

And everything went fine. But this double table, one for thead, one for tbody is astonishing me...

Comment: My datatables have <tbody></tbody> in the HTML, I don't know if that would make any difference to yours.

Comment: I'll try that and I'll tell you. Thanks